# Defining `marker-end` completely using CSS

Tags: css, svg

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/marker-end) you can use CSS to define a `marker-end` value for an SVG `<path>`, but all the examples use a `url(#...)` syntax which refers to an existing element in the drawing.

Is it possible to define a marker completely inside the CSS, such that by changing a stylesheet it can change the marker style to a completely different shape?  As in, one that wasn't already defined in the image?

Or would I have to include all these options inside the image itself, and the CSS can only choose which one it uses?

(I tried a few `data:` URL solutions, didn't work for me.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking to change the complete marker element using CSS? I don't understand how this is related to changing just the marker-end.

Comment: Short answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

It's not completely impossible, but there are some obstacles. You can style the marker shape with CSS, but not by changing the style of the path that uses the marker. You need to change the style of the marker definition itself. Consequently, you would need a unique marker for every path you want to decorate, otherwise all elements referencing the same `<marker>` would change at once.

Also you can only change the presentation attributes of the **content** of the `<marker>` element. Its own attributes (`markerWidth`, `markerHeight`, `refX`, `refY`, `orient`) are all XML, not presentation attributes. But you **can** change the marker shape. One strategy might be to define multiple shapes, and set all of them to `display: none` save the one you currently want to show.

Or, since now Chrome and Firefox have implemented the `d` property in CSS, you can also redefine a shape like this:

```css
svg {
    width: 200px;
    display: block;
}
input ~ svg #marker {
    --shape: path('M2,2 H8 V8 H2 z');
    --color: green;
}
input:checked ~ svg #marker {
    --shape: path('M5,0 10,5 5,10 0,5 z');
    --color: red;
}
#marker path {    
    d: var(--shape);
    fill: var(--color);
}
#usage {
    stroke: black;
    marker-end: url(#marker);
}
```

```html
<input id="switch" type="checkbox"> <label for="switch">Switch marker</label>
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 30">
  <marker id="marker" viewBox="0 0 10 10" orient="auto"
          markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" refX="5" refY="5">
     <path />
  </marker>
  <path id="usage" d="M5,18 25,12" />
</svg>
```

Lokking at this pattern, you might be tempted to compare it to the way you can inherit CSS custom properties inside the shadow DOM by setting them on `<use>` elements. Alas, this does not work for referenced markers:

```css
svg {
    width: 200px;
    display: block;
}
input ~ svg #usage {
    --shape: path('M2,2 H8 V8 H2 z');
    --color: green;
}
input:checked ~ svg #usage {
    --shape: path('M5,0 10,5 5,10 0,5 z');
    --color: red;
}
#marker path {    
    d: var(--shape);
    fill: var(--color);
}
#usage {
    stroke: black;
    marker-end: url(#marker);
}
```

```html
<input id="switch" type="checkbox"> <label for="switch">Switch marker</label>
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 30">
  <marker id="marker" viewBox="0 0 10 10" orient="auto"
          markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" refX="5" refY="5">
     <path />
  </marker>
  <path id="usage" d="M5,18 25,12" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a marker encoded as a data URL.

It works on Firefox but it seems [Chrome still doesn't support external markers](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109212).

```html
<svg viewBox="0 50 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <polyline fill="none" stroke="black"
      points="40,60 70,80" marker-end='url(data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20120%20120%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cmarker%20id%3D%22triangle%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2010%2010%22%20refX%3D%221%22%20refY%3D%225%22%20markerUnits%3D%22strokeWidth%22%20markerWidth%3D%2210%22%20markerHeight%3D%2210%22%20orient%3D%22auto%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M%200%200%20L%2010%205%20L%200%2010%20z%22%20fill%3D%22%23f00%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fmarker%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E#triangle)'/>
</svg>
```